# PHP - memcache randomly fails with - Cannot assign requested address (99)

Tags: php, memcached

I have changed my caching system (it is using more caching) and switched to PHP 7.1. Now from time to time (approx. 1 run out of 5) I got this error with memcache:

```
Notice: Memcache::connect(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Cannot assign requested address (99) 

Warning: Memcache::connect(): Can't connect to 127.0.0.1:11211, Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

What is causing this and why only sometimes? So far I have no problem witch this and on localhost, all is running OK as well.

Comment: From what I gather this might occur if the connection is attempted when another one is trying to connect at exactly the same time.

Comment: @apokryfos I have reduced memcache usage to half, but the problem is still the same. No improvement.

Comment: I don't think it's a usage problem, rather you might have something at some point (like an ajax call or something) that is double-firing so you get a connection attempt at exactly the same time.

Comment: @apokryfos But how can I prevent this scenario? Multiple users can access the same page at the same time if the treffic is high.

Comment: First you would need to verify that this is indeed the problem by having a small script connecting at regular intervals to make sure that the issue does not occur when connections are isolated. There's still a chance the problem is something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error can mean that you have opened and closed connections so quickly that TCP has no more available ports to create the next connection.

See if your memcached client has a setting to "pool" connections so they stay open.